# Ошибка при подключении к базе

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, у меня есть код

```
//Создается новый экземпляр класса MySqlConnection
 MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
//Подключение открывается
        cnt.Open();
//Создается команда
        MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();
    // SQL запрос команды
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username =" + username + "and pass =" + pass;
    //Запуск класса который считывает данные из БД
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
        {
//Выводится на экран через labelBalance.Text
            labelBalance.Text = "Баланс: " + reader["balance"].ToString();
        }
```

Так вот, он должен выводить баланс, который находится у пользователя, но почему-то пишет ошибку...

Может, я здесь что-то неправильно сделал?

```
 username = textUserName.Text;
 int.TryParse(textPassword.Text, out pass);
```

Код ошибки

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pass =123456' at line 1

**P.S**

И ещё скажите, у меня есть таблица, где содержаться Url сайтов. Так вот как заставить чтобы `WebBrowser1` считывал Url по очереди и показывал их?

Comment: Дай лучше код ошибки....

Comment: Ну вот.. Тут пишет, что у тебя ошибка в SQL syntax, дальше кидай  at line 1

Comment: Да но посмотрите на мой первый пост, там вроде ошибки нету.. Может надо скинуть скрипты БД?

Comment: strProvider может тут ошибка? всего же не видно...

Comment: host = "localhost";
            database = "RPGGame";
            user = "RPGGame";
            password = "159357";

            strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;

Comment: а в SELECT не имеет смысла заключить значения username и pass в апострофы? А то получается значение CommandText `SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username =Васяand pass =парол` . Возможно, в зависимости от типа поля username ещё и без пробела перед `and`

Comment: Вот строение моей БД 

http://s017.radikal.ru/i433/1201/98/83c40041b71e.png

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую сразу писать код качественно.

Разберитесь с тем, как пользоваться параметрами запроса, и используйте их.

Конкретно этот код не работает, потому что Вы строковый литерал, хранящийся в переменной `username`, при подстановке в запрос не берёте в апострофы.

Comment: Можете написать пример?

Comment: `..="SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username ='  " + username + " ' and pass =' " + pass+" ' ";`

Comment: Ошибка, всё равно осталась :(

Comment: Ошибка все та же?

Comment: Ага всё таке.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pass =123456' at line 1

Comment: Напечатайте или посмотрите в отладчике значение command.CommandText

Comment: А вы точно добавлили одинарные кавычки после знака равно? Просто в сообщении об ошибке их не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую такие запросы писать через функцию форматирования строки, чтобы не путаться в апострофах. Не хнаю как на сях, в дельфи было бы так

```
format('SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username ="%s" and pass = "%s"',[username,pass])
```

Comment: а еще условия удобно в скобки брать для наглядности